# IQbservable<> needs assembly already in project

Tags: c#, system.reactive, netmq

Using a project that targets .Net 4.5, I have a section of code that does this

```
public static IObservable<string> Receive(SubscriberSocket subp)
{
    return Observable
        .Create<string>(o =>
            Observable.Using<string, SubscriberSocket>(() =>
            {
                subp.Connect("inproc://test");
                subp.Subscribe("");
                return subp;
            }, sub =>
                Observable.FromEventPattern<EventHandler<NetMQSocketEventArgs>, NetMQSocketEventArgs>(
                    h => sub.ReceiveReady += h,
                    h => sub.ReceiveReady -= h)
                .Select(x => sub.ReceiveString()))
        .Subscribe(o));
}
```

However, it complains that I need `System.Reactive.Interfaces, Version=3.0.0.0`  even though that assembly has been added into the project?

> /home/idf/Documents/csharp/NetMQObs/TestNetMQ/TestNetMQ/Program.cs(25,25): Error CS0012: The type 'IQbservable<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Reactive.Interfaces, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94bc3704cddfc263'. (CS0012) (TestNetMQ)

After adding the 2.2.5 versions as suggested below, now I get this error. Changing the call to `ReceiveFrameString` compiles, but YMMV.

```
/home/idf/Documents/csharp/NetMQObs/TestNetMQ/TestNetMQ/Program.cs(42,42): Error CS1061: 'SubscriberSocket' does not contain a definition for 'ReceiveString' and no extension method 'ReceiveString' accepting a first argument of type 'SubscriberSocket' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (TestNetMQ)
```

Comment: Just a side note - this implementation is bad - you'll end up disposing your `SubscriberSocket` when the first subscription terminates. Why are you passing in `SubscriberSocket subp`?

Comment: It also looks like NetMQ uses Rx-Core 2.2.5 and Rx-Interfaces 2.2.5. Perhaps that's causing you grief? Can you try those versions?

Comment: @Richard.Schneider - `IQbservable` is the correct type here for this error. I've rolled back your edit.

Comment: @Enigmativity the 2.2.5 suggestion helps. However now I get a new error. See the edit in the end of the post. Since this is bad design on my part, how do you suggest I modify it? I will open a new question.

Comment: @Enigmativity see this new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46748396/how-to-avoid-disposing-socket

Comment: To everyone - please don't edit the title - `IQservable` is the correct type, not `IObservable`. This is the same distinction as `IQueryable` versus `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 0):

It also looks like NetMQ uses Rx-Core 2.2.5 and Rx-Interfaces 2.2.5.

By putting in the wrong library (`Version=3.0.0.0`) you are causing this error.